# Can I style Facebook comments?

Tags: css, facebook

Is it possible, with the new Facebook commenting system to restyle them? I only need two 'simple' changes: :link colour & a font change.

I have been reading the docs & have tried out some tests to no avail.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/comments_(XFBML)/

I have also read [this blog post](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/490/) that says that it's not possible anymore, BUT I know there are sites that still custom css - I just cannot get mine to work..

Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those documents are for the old FBML implementation of the comments box, the current docs are at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/

Have you any examples of sites customising the plugin? It shouldn't really be possible since it's served from an iframe, it's possible those sites are implementing their own comments logic